# Using PrimeFaces Global Filter?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

as Mentioned in primefaces [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf) i am trying to create a global filter for datatable . there i am unable to understand what does **carsTable** means, in the code fragment

```
 <h:form>  

     <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}"  
             emptyMessage="No cars found with given criteria">  

          <f:facet name="header">  
             <p:outputPanel>  
                 <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />  
                 <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="carsTable.filter()" style="width:150px"/>  
             </p:outputPanel>  
         </f:facet>
```

when i use **my datatableId**  inplace of **carsTable** iam getting an javascript error as Undefined Id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a typo in the showcase code display.  Their is a missing attribute on the `<p:dataTable>` component called `widgetVar`.  This attribute declares the unique Javascript identifier for this client side component.  The code should show this:

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}"
   widgetVar="carsTable" emptyMessage="No cars found with given criteria">
...
```

For some reason the client side function `filter()` is not declared in the PF Guide 2.2 under the Client DOM for dataTable, however I know it is there and I use it.